# Optimize SOLR Highlighter

Tags: performance, optimization, solr, highlight, highlighting

I am attempting to optimize highlighting in my SOLR instance as this seems to slow down queries by 2 orders of magnitude. I have a tokenized field index and stored with following definition:

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="\+" replacement="%2B"/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.UAX29URLEmailTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords_en.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="\+" replacement="%2B"/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.UAX29URLEmailTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords_en.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Term vectors etc are also generated:

```
<field name="Events" type="text_general" multiValued="true" stored="true" indexed="true" termVectors="true" termPositions="true"  termOffsets="true"/>
```

For the highlight component I use the default SOLR config. The query I try uses FastVectorHighlighter but still takes ~1500ms, which is awfully long for ~1000 docs with 10-20 values stored in the field per doc. Here is the query:

```
q=Events:http\://mydomain.com/resource/term/906&fq=(Document_Code:[*+TO+*])&hl.requireFieldMatch=true&facet=true&hl.simple.pre=<b>&hl.fl=*&hl=true&rows=10&version=2&fl=uri,Document_Type,Document_Title,Modification_Date,Study&hl.snippets=1&hl.useFastVectorHighlighter=true
```

What I find curious is that in the solr admin stats a single query generates 9146 requests to HtmlFormatter and GapFragmenter. Any thoughts on why this might be happening and how the performance of the highlighter can be improved?

Comment: I am using Solr 3.6 running on Tomcat 7.0.28

Comment: Running the same query on a similar field that does not have termVectors enabled shows no significant difference in response time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that the problem is caused by "hl.fl=*", which caused the DefaultSolrHighlighter to iterate over a relatively large number of fields (in my index) for each document found (10 max  in my case). This causes the additional O(n^2) time. Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
for (int i = 0; i < docs.size(); i++) {
  int docId = iterator.nextDoc();
  Document doc = searcher.doc(docId, fset);
  NamedList docSummaries = new SimpleOrderedMap();
  for (String fieldName : fieldNames) {
    fieldName = fieldName.trim();
    if( useFastVectorHighlighter( params, schema, fieldName ) )
      doHighlightingByFastVectorHighlighter( fvh, fieldQuery, req, docSummaries, docId, doc, fieldName );
    else
      doHighlightingByHighlighter( query, req, docSummaries, docId, doc, fieldName );
  }
  String printId = schema.printableUniqueKey(doc);
  fragments.add(printId == null ? null : printId, docSummaries);
}
```

Reducing the number of fields should improve the behaviour greatly. However, in my case I cannot reduce it bellow 20 fields, so I will check whether enabling the FastVectorHighlighter for all of them will improve the overall performance.

I was also wondering whether we could reduce this list even further by using some info from the matching docs (which are already available at this point).

**Update**

Using FastVectorHighlighter for all fields (set *termVectors*, *termPositions* and *termOffsets* to *true* for all tokenized fields) did indeed improve the highlighting speed by an order of magnitude, so that now all queries run < 1s. The size of the index increased by 3 times its original value (from 500M to 2G). There is also a problem with how the fragments for multivalued fields are generated, but the improvement of performance is high enough.

Comment: Beware that there seems to be a range of issues with the highlighting in 3.6. In addition to the problem with multivalued fields, numeric fields seem to be automatically ignored by the highlighter (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3050) and date range queries cannot be evaluated at all (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3704).